# Request returning 400 bad request in Tomcat 8

Tags: java, http, tomcat, urlencode

I have a Java Web application deployed in tomcat.

I receive 400 Bad request from Tomcat 8 if my URL is like this

```
https://<serverurl>?cmisSelector=object&objectId=TyNGT0wjJSMwMDAjMDAjIyMj&filter=cmis:createdBy,a:b:ab,a:b:abc&renditionFilter=cmis:thumbnail,application/pdf,image/bmp,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png
```

Which is encoded as

```
https%3A%2F%2F%3Cserverurl%3E%3FcmisSelector%3Dobject%26objectId%3DTyNGT0wjJSMwMDAjMDAjIyMj%26filter%3Dcmis%3AcreatedBy%2Ca%3Ab%3Aab%2Ca%3Ab%3Aabc%26renditionFilter%3Dcmis%3Athumbnail%2Capplication%2Fpdf%2Cimage%2Fbmp%2Cimage%2Fgif%2Cimage%2Fjpeg%2Cimage%2Fpng
```

But if i remove the a:b:ab,a:b:abc and renditionFilter=cmis:thumbnail,application/pdf,image/bmp,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png from the URL then the it works, this URL is formed like below

```
https://<serverurl>?cmisSelector=object&objectId=TyNGT0wjJSMwMDAjMDAjIyMj&filter=cmis:createdBy
```

Seems to be some URL encoding issue but not able to find out the exact issue.

Comment: Don't we have to escape the `:` with `%3A`?

Comment: yes its happening with %3A only

Comment: Try `https://<serverurl>?cmisSelector=object&objectId=TyNGT0wjJSMwMDAjMDAjIyMj&filter=cmis%3AcreatedBy%2Ca%3Ab%3Aab%2Ca%3Ab%3Aabc&renditionFilter%3Dcmis%3Athumbnail%2Capplication%2Fpdf%2Cimage%2Fbmp%2Cimage%2Fgif%2Cimage%2Fjpeg%2Cimage%2Fpng`

Answer (score 2):

By default Tomcat returns a HTTP Bad Request (400) if the URL contains a forward or backward slash `/` (%2F) and `\` (%5C) respectively. This is done as a security measure.

You can disable that feature and allow those characters by setting the following system properties (for instance in `catalina.properties` or in `CATALINA_OPTS`):

```
-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true

### You may not need this one, as you only have forward slashes
-Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.ALLOW_BACKSLASH=true
```

Comment: In recent Tomcats, it would be better to use the [`encodedSolidusHandling`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes) attribute on your `<Connector>` instead of a system property because it can be set on a per-connector basis instead of globally.